# SQL Server 2008 user instance database creation failure within an asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to create a database within the app_data folder of an asp.net mvc project using the IDE, but i am getting a "Required Components Missing" message indicating "Connections to SQL Server files (*.mdf) requireSQL Express 2005 ....."

I am using
- Windows 7 Enterprise
- VS2008 Team System SP1 
- SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition SP1

I have altered the database connection to use the default instance by setting to blank using

```
Tools -> Options -> Database Tools -> Data Connection : SQL Server Instance Name
```

I also note from the SQL Server Books Online that the user instance feature will be removed in the future, but for now it suits my effort in developing an application where a number of people are working on the project.

Has anyone managed to create a database in the same manner? 
It appears Nerd Dinner has done so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attached user-instance database in the `App_Data` will work only with a SQL Server **Express** edition - 2005 or 2008.

It does not work with a full SQL Server edition, like Web, Workgroup, Standard, Enterprise or Developer. It does not - no way - no trick to make it work - does not - period.

If you want to use that mechanism of attaching a user instance database in your `App_Data` folder, you must use SQL Server 2005/2008 Express.